# I get notices for all of the $_POST's I have

Tags: php

I have a couple of pages in my application. In the first page (create_session.php) which is below the user submits the form and goes onto the next page (QandATable.php).

```
<form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">

<p>
    <strong>
        Your Session ID: 
    </strong>
    <span id="idFont">
        <?php echo $id; ?>
    </span>
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<p>
    <strong>
        Date:
    </strong> 
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dateChosen" readonly="readonly" />
<p>
    <strong>
        Start Time:
    </strong> 
    <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="timeChosen" readonly="readonly" />

<p>
    <input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion"/>
</p> 

</form>
```

Now if $_POST['id'] equals 1, then there is only 1 exam, but if it it is more than 1, then there are multiple exams which is where the problem occurs.

Lets say I wanted 2 exams and I submit the form to the QandATable.php, then the first exam has no problems, but after I finish the first exam and then submit the form (This form would submit to itself), then for the second exam, I suddenly get notices for all of the $_POST I have in the code below.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['id'])) 
{
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
}


if (isset($_POST['dateChosen'])) 
{
    $_SESSION['dateChosen'] = $_POST['dateChosen'];
}

if (isset($_POST['timeChosen'])) 
{
    $_SESSION['timeChosen'] = $_POST['timeChosen'];
}

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$insert = array();

for ($i = 1, $n = $_POST['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i)
{
    $insert[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['id'] ) . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i) . "',' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['timeChosen'] ) . "',' ". mysql_real_escape_string( date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['dateChosen'] ) ) ) . "'";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Session (SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate) 
VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insert) . ")";

mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();    
?>
```

So what I want to know is that when I have multiple exams, why am I getting notices on all of the $_POST's after the first exam has been completed? All the notices are undefined indexes on all the posts.

Comment: What "notices" are you getting?

Comment: @Bono These are all undefined indexes on all the $_POST. So undefined index 'id', 'timeChosen' and 'dateChosen' but this only happens after first exam is complete and when I am on the page ready to create the second exam

Comment: Can you give us the complete warning php gives you?

Another point: you have white spaces in front of all your values: "' ". mysql_real... I think you don't want them in your database.

Comment: undefined index 'id' in Mobile_app/QandATable.php on line 29. undefined index 'timeChosen' in Mobile_app/QandATable.php on line 35.undefined index 'dateChosen' in Mobile_app/QandATable.php on line 41

Comment: What's the purpose of the for loop? The form has to be submitted for each exam, correct? Let me make sure I have your process correct. When you have multiple exams you fill out the form and submit it. Everything works fine. Then, since the form posts to itself, you fill out the form again for your second exam and post. That's when you hit errors? Correct?

Comment: @Matt More, yes that is correct, you hit the nail on the head there :)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `undefined index` errors because when you view the page without posting a form, the `$_POST` data you're looking for does not exist.

Check if the post data exists before trying to use it:

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['timeChosen'], $_POST['dateChosen']))
{

  $insert = array();

  for ($i = 1, $n = $_POST['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i)
  {
    $insert[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['id'] ) . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i) . "',' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['timeChosen'] ) . "',' ". mysql_real_escape_string( date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['dateChosen'] ) ) ) . "'";
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Session (SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate) 
  VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insert) . ")";


  mysql_query($sql);

}
```

Or use `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` if you know that the correct post data will always be present on a POST request.

Comment: I will test this in about 20 mins and get back to you to tell you if it works or not, I have a quick errand to do :)